# How to enable compile on save on Visual Studio with sfdx-vscode plugin?

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

How to enable or configure "Salesforce Extensions for VS Code" plugin on Visual studio code IDE to compile my Apex,Visualforce on the scratch org when I save the file locally.

I have just started using it and I have to manually run the command `sfdx force:source:push` either from command prompt or from the command pallette in IDE.

Is there an easy option like we had in Mavensmate and Force IDE?

**Update**

I opened issue with salesforcedx-vscode project:

- [GitHub Issue: Does not show even basic semantic errors until source is pushed to server](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/195)

Comment: Most recent update from the GutHub issue: `This isn't on our roadmap at this time. We are looking into what we can do to improve the Aura and Visualforce language servers, but we don't have any timeline right now.`

Comment: @Robs I have seen on one of the blogs that they are suggesting nodemon util to get this working as a workaround. Because there is a workaround maybe they are not treating as high priority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compile your code automatically like you did before with the first version of the Eclipse plugin. The new plugin makes use of the [Language Server Protocole](https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol) which will help you find errors locally, but you'll still have to use `sfdx force:source:push` to compile everything.

If you have access to the Trailblazer Community, there is a thread about this [here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1&fId=0D53A00003DkTtM).

Additionally, you can automatically push your changes to your Scratch Org using Nodemon, as described in [this blog post](https://ntotten.com/2018/01/17/using-nodemon-to-autopush-sfdx-project-changes/).

Comment: Thanks. Both the links are pointing to the same github url. Also, it is not showing any error message in VScode if I write any gibberish. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/BnTIJ

Comment: Sorry, updated the link ^^Not sure what is currently supported by the language server, it's a good question. You could either ask on the Chatter post or directly on the SalesforceDX vscode plugin github: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues

Comment: Thanks. Luckily, I was part of pilot program so have access to the community. Posted a comment for Wade and Josh. I hope they will look into it and provide update. Thanks again.

Comment: Just added an additional way to do it as described in Nathan Totten's blog post :)

Comment: Is there any possibility we connect scratch org with MavensMate in VS code?

Comment: What if I get this error on source:push

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for auto deploy, you can set this in the workspace settings...
To push files each time you save them, set the user or workspace setting

```
 salesforcedx-vscode-core.push-or-deploy-on-save.enabled:true
```

### Reference to Article

https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/package-development-model

Comment: I upvoted because it does deploy when a file is saved, but only when done via an open folder (project), when "Saving" the same file from within a "Workspace" it does not deploy.

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been added in a Feature Preview option to the Salesforce VS-Code extension.  [Click here](https://medium.com/@idanblich/salesforce-vs-code-new-push-or-deploy-code-on-save-3f3fe5d76492) for details.