# Any work around on compiling file on save in vscode for sandbox?

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I want to use Visual Studio Code for development in my sandbox and I was able to setup as per this [article](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Develop-Against-Any-Org-in-Visual-Studio-Code).

Everything is working fine but whenever I make any change to ApexClass, I need to right click on the file and choose the option `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org` or run the below command

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p path/to/source
```

Has anyone come up with a hack/workaround for this problem so that ApexClass is automatically compiled as it does in Force IDE/MavensMate?

**NOTE**: [This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197183/how-to-enable-compile-on-save-on-visual-studio-with-sfdx-vscode-plugin) is about scratch orgs and this is about sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce is still working on this feature and I see this part of the release [PR](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/pull/854/files) shortly .Good news !!!

However note that it will still use the Metadata API deployment which is not bad but takes time .Seems like Salesforce will fix this and improve the performance under the hood .

However you should be able to use the vscode [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MohithShrivastava.dx-code-companion) I personally built that uses tooling api under the hood and I have observed to be much faster for apex , vf, web components and aura bundles .These are not hard to build if you know Typescript and VScode extension apis and SalesforceDx cli.

Note that this extension will work only once you install the custom cli plugin i built by running `sfdx:plugins install mo-dx-plugin`

Comment: Just finished installing and I can confirm that it is working. Thank you so much for your time in building this tool and answering my question/tweet.

Comment: You are welcome and any time you need anything with it ,do let me know !!